# XSLT for Tridion field to modify @class and inject a <span> not working

Tags: 2011, xslt

See related question ([Using XSLT within Schema to manipulate HTML output from Component](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/using-xslt-within-schema-to-manipulate-html-output-from-component))

I have added the following  to the XSLT for a content field within a schema...

```
<template match="*[contains(@class, &apos;cta-button-secondary&apos;)]">
    <copy>
        <attribute name="href">
        <value-of select="./@href"></value-of>
        </attribute>
    <attribute name="class">cta-button secondary</attribute>
    <element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <value-of select="."></value-of>
    </element>
    </copy>
</template>
```

This works perfectly in the W3C XSLT debugger but when I try and use it in Tridion it doesn't seem to be applying. I am aware that this should be executed when the field content is updated rather than on publish but it doesn't seem to work...

The XSLT should find any `<a>` elements with a `class="cta-button-secondary"` and replace the class with `class="cta-button secondary"` (note: 2 classes instead of 1) and inject a `<span>` element around the `<a>` value.

Full XSLT:

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
        <template match="/ | node() | @*">
            <copy>
                <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
            </copy>
        </template>                                                 <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
                                                        <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
                                                    </template>
                                                    <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
                                                        <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
                                                        <text> </text>
                                                    </template>
    <template match="*[contains(@class, &apos;cta-button-primary&apos;)]">
        <copy>
            <attribute name="href">
            <value-of select="./@href"></value-of>
            </attribute>
        <attribute name="class">cta-button primary</attribute>
        <element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <value-of select="."></value-of>
        </element>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="*[contains(@class, &apos;cta-button-secondary&apos;)]">
        <copy>
            <attribute name="href">
            <value-of select="./@href"></value-of>
            </attribute>
        <attribute name="class">cta-button secondary</attribute>
        <element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <value-of select="."></value-of>
        </element>
        </copy>
    </template>
    </stylesheet>
```

Full XML:

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:3f71252b-6e99-47f2-8906-ff4488c188a1">
    <body>
        <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Thanks to the hard work of our supporters we increased what we spent on cancer services to a record £105.9 million in 2011. That's £10 million more than in 2010.</p>
        <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">For a full breakdown of these charts, take a look at our <a href="#" class="cta-button-primary">Annual report and accounts 2011</a> or <a href="#" class="cta-button-secondary">Our 2011 achievements.</a></p>
    </body>
</Content>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to add namespace while creating span tag, try removing namespace.

`SPAN` is a valid tag and it's not required to add on `new-inline-tags`

### Update:

While going through your XSLT, I see that you have written a template which can match for any element and it tries to create a `href` attribute which looks for `@href` attribute.

But actually, you are trying to target only `<a>` tags not all other tags.

Use below XSLT which can be used as a single template match, which does for you

```
<template match="a">
    <choose>
        <when test="*[contains(@class, &apos;cta-button-primary&apos;)]">
            <copy>
                <attribute name="href">
                    <value-of select="./@href"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="class">cta-button primary</attribute>
                <element name="span">
                    <value-of select="."/>
                </element>
            </copy>
        </when>
        <when test="*[contains(@class, &apos;cta-button-secondary&apos;)]">
            <copy>
                <attribute name="href">
                    <value-of select="./@href"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="class">cta-button secondary</attribute>
                <element name="span">
                    <value-of select="."/>
                </element>
            </copy>
        </when>
    </choose>
</template>
```

Comment: I had already removed the namespace whilst tinkering and even with an empty span element it still needed inclusion within this config file before it started working.

Comment: @JohnAskew: The field "new-inline-tags" is used for non-valid tags. But in your case, am thinking what are the possibilities of not working

Comment: I'm not sure why. Had me scratching my head too but I'll mark this as the correct answer as it should work.

Answer (score 4):

This is now working. The fix was...

Had to add **span** to **new-inline-tags** in **%TRIDION_HOME%\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\TcmXhtml\TcmXHTML.config** for this to work.

If the element I am adding is not present in this config file under new-inline tags then the XSLT will fail and not apply the template.