# Tridion RichText Add Class

Tags: sdl-tridion

I'm working on tridion 2013, and would like to append CSS class to one of the  element of the rich text source code. What are the options I have? How can I add style to the CMS (below picture)

[image]

Test more

Comment: After setting up the styles, note that the specific rich text format area needs to allow the styles and the user needs to have selected an element that matches the CSS selector defined for the "custom" style.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure this hasn't changed recently... [here's how to do it on Tridion 9.1](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-D95860F7-15DF-4091-B24E-3539F7CB33C4).

Answer (score 3):

You should see many examples of this through a few simple google searches (other search engines do exist ;) )

Using two terms from your own question got me what I think is the answer... (and a little bit more).

[Rich Text Box: Option to select multiple styles from drop down](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19606/rich-text-box-option-to-select-multiple-styles-from-drop-down/19608)

And [the link to the 2013 SP1 Documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C4121F61-1710-4A01-8931-7FE19B24DCAD).